# RFC-822 date-time format in RSS 2.0 feeds: CET not accepted?

Tags: java, date, formatting, rss, atom-feed

[Updated with working solution]
I have an RSS feed which gets displayed correctly in RSS clients, but when being validated by http://feedvalidator.org I get this error:

```
pubDate must be an RFC-822 date-time
```

My date is formatted as follows:

**`Wed, 27 Feb 2013 17:18:15 CET`**

Any idea what could be wrong?
Could it be the timezone?

## **SOLUTION**

Thanks to Calum I got a valid RSS feed now. Reason was the `CET` not being supported in the `pubDate`.

The following Java Code is working now fine:

```
String pubDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) indicates it only supports a very limited set of symbolic timezone names; just UTC and US ones:

```
 zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                             ; North American : UT
             /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
             /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
             /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
             /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
             /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                             ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                             ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
             / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                             ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

You probably need to specify as an offset to UTC.

Since you say you're using Java, it looks like [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) will give you an RFC-822 compliant date if you use `Z` to format the zone in your time format (rather than `z`).

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the `Z` to format the time zone as [Calum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8434/calum) said, but don't forget to specify the `Locale` too or else it won't work if the computer is not in English...

Here is my working code :

```
new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US).format(new Date());
```